# Investigating the effect of solvents (protic vs aprotic) on the alkaline hydrolysis of ethyl acetate using a conductivity meter

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, solvents, transition-state-theory

What different areas about solvents can be explored with the conductivities collected of the alkaline hydrolysis of ethyl acetate in propanone and ethanol? 
$$\ce{CH3COOC2H5 + NaOH -> CH3COONa + C2H5OH}$$

Currently, I am looking at the effect on activation energy, rates, and rate constants and the overall conversion of ethyl acetate to sodium acetate at the end of the ten minutes of the reaction in the two solvents (to see which is more favorable).

Will I be able to integrate transition state theory and Gibbs equations in any way possible?